# Addressing the problem of fat thumbs

Tags: feature-request, voting, voting-limits

Original question posted [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5572/how-best-to-address-the-problem-of-fat-thumbs).

I occasionally use the Stack Exchange app for iOS when reading or answering questions on this site.

I hold the phone in my left hand and scroll with my thumb along the left side of the screen. This detail turns out to be important because I discovered today that my scrolling errantly triggered a vote on an answer. What is worse, it was a downvote on an answer I would normally upvote.

Unfortunately, I discovered the error just under an hour after the vote had been issued. By this time, attempts to change the vote result in an error message stating "You last voted on this answer 52 minutes ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

I am disappointed that I appear to have no anonymous recourse to change my vote.

Do I comment to the answerer an embarrassing: "Sorry, I have fat thumbs. If you'll waste your time making an unimportant edit, I'll remove my errant downvote?"

Do I shrug and sigh "C'est la vie" and hope that the community overthrows my errant vote with a tide of upvotes?

The advice I received on meta was to raise a feature request here. I have considered what I think to be an appropriate solution that preserves the intent of the vote-locking policy (that is, to prevent "tactical downvoting"), and permit a user to correct genuine human error.

The solution I propose is this: simply provide a threshold under which undoing votes is permitted. The threshold could be something like, "You may undo up to five of your own votes per month," or, "You may undo ten votes for the lifetime of your account".

The exact numbers above are perhaps unimportant. What is important to me, though, is that I have a means to correct an honest mistake without drawing undue attention to the error and without compromising the intent of the locking policy.